# Remove item with $product_id - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Made a function where the customer get a product added to the cart when they reach a specific amount.

**Example of when customer reaches level 3 and get the product added.**

```
// Bonus products
$product_1 = '4751'; 
$product_2 = '4752'; 
$product_3 = '4753'; 

// Get cart value in a clean format
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$cart_total = html_entity_decode($cart_total, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$cart_total_format = strip_tags($cart_total);
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9]/", "", $cart_total_format);
$sum_raw = $cart_value;

// Set the sum level 
$level3 = '1500';

// Check sum and apply product
if ($sum_raw >= $level3) {

// Cycle through each product in the cart and check for match
$found = 'false';
foreach (WC()->cart->cart_contents as $item) {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $item['variation_id'];

    if ($product_id == $product_3) {
        $found = 'true';
    }
}

// If product found we do nothing 
if ($found == 'true') {}
// else we will add it
else {
    //We add the product
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_3);
```

If customer decides to remove item's so this statement is true i want to be able to remove it again.

```
if ($sum_raw < $level3) {

    // Trying to remove item
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if ($cart_item['variation_id'] == $product_3) {

            //remove single product
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($product_3);
        }
    }
}
```

Am do not manage to remove the product from cart. Any ideas what am doing wrong here? Have been searching around without finding any solution that works for me.

**Solution**

With help from @Rohil_PHPBeginner & @WisdmLabs I came to this solution that did the job for me.

```
global $woocommerce;
// Check if sum
if ($sum_raw < $level3) {
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {

        if ($cart_item['variation_id'] == $product_3) {
            //remove single product
            $woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WC_Cart::remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );

Comment: Chould i change WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($product_3);  for that ?

Comment: What is that variable $product_3?

Comment: $product_3 = '4753';  , It's the variation ID of the product

Comment: remove_cart_item() it takes parameter as $cart_item_key

Comment: And how would i do that ? Have been trying many solutions and suggestions but i can't just get it to work.

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg Would you rather post this as Answer,

Comment: Adding this as I found an issue using this code with a simple product instead of a variable product. to make this work in both cases instead of $cart_item['variation_id'] set a variable like so:
$prod_id = ( isset( $cart_item['variation_id'] ) && $cart_item['variation_id'] != 0 ) ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];

This way if there is no variation ID the product ID will still match.

Comment: Hopefully, this article https://wpza.net/how-to-remove-cart-items-by-id/ helps, as it discusses both `WC()` and `$woocommerce` methods to use.

Comment: `preg_filter("/[^0-9]/", "", $cart_total_format)` should be `preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $cart_total_format)`.  `preg_filter()` is over-kill / doing too much.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you're using `remove_cart_item` incorrectly. If you go through the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_remove_cart_item), you will find that it accepts **cart_item_key** as parameter (as wisdmLabs mentioned in comment).

You are using it like so:

```
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($product_3);
```

Try this instead:

```
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
```

After updating that line, I think you will able to remove product.

Comment: Thanks, That helped me to solve it.  Will update my post with the solution for others to see.

Comment: The link is not working. please update it.

Answer (score 6):

Use this for **latest versions of WooCommerce**:

```
$cartId = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( 'PUT PRODUCT ID IN HERE' );
$cartItemKey = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cartId );
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cartItemKey );
```

replace PRODUCT ID with yours.