# Remove product if card value < x

Tags: php, wordpress, action, product

I hope someone can help.  I've set up some code ([thanks to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569881/remove-item-with-product-id-woocommerce)) that adds a product to my cart if the value of the cart is over $50.

That works.  However, if the value is less than $50, I want to make sure that product is NOT in the cart.  So say a user adds a product, the additional product is added, but they then remove a product so the value is under $50 (not including the new product added!) ... I want it to remove the product that was added.

I tried to implement the code as in the post mentioned above:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' ); 

function add_product_to_cart() {
// Bonus products
$product_1 = '4751'; 
$product_2 = '4752'; 
$product_3 = '24711'; 

// Get cart value in a clean format
$cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
$cart_total = html_entity_decode($cart_total, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$cart_total_format = strip_tags($cart_total);
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9]/", "", $cart_total_format);
$sum_raw = $cart_value;

// Set the sum level 
$level3 = '50';

// Check sum and apply product
if ($sum_raw >= $level3) {

    // Cycle through each product in the cart and check for match
    $found = 'false';
        foreach (WC()->cart->cart_contents as $item) {
            global $product;
            $product_id = $item['variation_id'];

            if ($product_id == $product_3) {
                $found = 'true';
            }
        }

    // If product found we do nothing 
        if ($found == 'true') {}
    // else we will add it
        else {
        //We add the product
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_3);
        }
}


// Check if sum
if ($sum_raw < $level3) {
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key =>     $cart_item) {

        if ($cart_item['variation_id'] == $product_3) {
                //remove single product
                $woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But it's not removing the product. :/  Anyone got any ideas why it wouldn't work, or if there's a better solution to check the cart: if cart > $50 add a product... if it ever changes and goes < $50, remove that same product...

And also exclude that newly added product from the checks (so < $50 NOT including that product that's just been added programmatically).

Please help! :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have to change this line :

```
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9]/", "", $cart_total_format);
```

to (add - minus):

```
$cart_value = preg_filter("/[^0-9\-]/", "", $cart_total_format);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didn't seem to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... you are currently trying to update on "add" action while it should on "remove" action.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_product_from_cart' );
function remove_product_from_cart() {
    // Run only in the Cart or Checkout Page
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {


        /*
         GET THE CART TOTAL 
         */

        // Set the product ID to remove
        $prod_to_remove = PRODUCT-ID-TO-BE-REMOVED;

        // Cycle through each product in the cart
        foreach( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $prod_in_cart ) {
            // Get the Variation or Product ID
            $prod_id = ( isset( $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] ) && $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] != 0 ) ? $prod_in_cart['variation_id'] : $prod_in_cart['product_id'];
            // Check to see if IDs match
            if( $prod_to_remove == $prod_id ) {
                // Get it's unique ID within the Cart
                $prod_unique_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $prod_id );
                // Remove it from the cart by un-setting it
                unset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[$prod_unique_id] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything.  You can test it here:  http://tulaforlife.staging.wpengine.com/my-cart/  --- Add an item over $50, and it'll add the gift card of $25, however remove the item so that the value is under $50 and the gift card stays :(